# What is the usual approach for things like this (Python multithreading)?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
def start_threads(self):
    thread_pool = []
    for obj in self._objs_list:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._do_task, args=(obj,))
        thread_pool.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    for thread in thread_pool:
        thread.join()

    self._do_final_task()
```

`_do_task` is basically a method which process some I/O operations and I want to to execute it in parallel for each `obj` in `self._objs_list`

I want `self._do_final_task()` to be executed only once all the threads finished their job.

My code works, however it is very ugly and immature (it seems). Is there a more elegant way of doing so?

Comment: If you would like your working code reviewed, use [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Will do.

Comment: If you want to rephrase the question as “What is the usual approach for things like this?”, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

While it can be useful to create a `Thread` without starting it, a helper function that does so **automatically** often makes sense.  That helper can be a **context manager** to handle the `join` as well:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def spawn(*a,**kw):
  t=threading.Thread(*a,**kw)
  t.start()
  try: yield t
  finally: t.join()

class …:
  def start_threads(self):
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as es:
      for obj in self._objs_list:
        es.enter_context(spawn(target=self._do_task, args=(obj,)))
    self._do_final_task()

  …
```